# Hex Numbers to Text

Tags: unicode, binary, hex, binaries

What is the method to convert hex numbers to text. For example 54 68 6f 6d 61 73 in text could be Thomas. I think I am mis-conceptualizing hex decimals with binaries and how they work.

Comment: Do you seek implementation in general or you want to know how to do it in specific language?

Comment: If you open a file in a hex editor, you'd see hex numbers. But it's just bytes so if you know the encoding of the file you can read it and convert it to Unicode.

Comment: @RafalZiolkowski I just wanted to know the implementation in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From powershell I find it like this.  Hint, I used the [Char]acter and Convert .NET classes.

```
$1=[Char][Convert]::ToUInt32('54',16)
$2=[Char][Convert]::ToUInt32('68',16)
$3=[Char][Convert]::ToUInt32('6f',16)
$4=[Char][Convert]::ToUInt32('6d',16)
$5=[Char][Convert]::ToUInt32('61',16)
$6=[Char][Convert]::ToUInt32('73',16)

$1+$2+$3+$4+$5+$6
```

Result

```
Thomas
```

In case you want to manipulate any other formats, find the syntax here.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The main idea here (and I think this is what you’re asking) is that each Unicode symbol in the text is represented using its code point value, in hexadecimal notation.

For example, the symbol `a` is [U+0061 LATIN SMALL LETTER A](http://codepoints.net/U+0061) as per the Unicode standard, so you could represent it as `0x61` or `61` in hex.

This works well for ASCII symbols. For higher code points, it depends on the representation. For example, the list of hexadecimal digits could refer to the UTF-8-encoded form of the string.

Comment: I wish they allowed us to mark two answers as helpful !! Appreciated your input !!